# Where is the documentation to use the Facebook SDK for Windows Phone?

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1, codeplex

Hi where is the current documentation to use the Facebook SDK on Windows Phone to authenticate users? I checked Codeplex... but I'm not finding anything.

Answer (score 2):

The main docs are at http://csharpsdk.org/docs/ - at the time of writing there aren't any windows phone specific docs though; perhaps you just include the SDK and code against it like any other library, and the general SDK docs should be OK for use with Windows phone?

{edit} the general docs do talk about windows phone, and it's mentioned in the FAQ too {/edit}

Answer (score 2):

For now you can check the WP7 sample at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows-phone-sample